# Why isn't this stochastic integral trivial?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have a stopping time $\tau$ and a stochastic process $f$.

Then the following equation is true:

\begin{equation}
\int^{t\wedge\tau}_{0}f(s)dW(s)=\int^{t}_{0}f(s)\chi_{[0,\tau]}(s)dW(s)
\end{equation}

Can someone explain why isn't it trivial as it is with a 'normal' Riemann integral?

Comment: $\int^{t}_{0}f(s)\chi_{[0,\tau]}(s)dW(s)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(s)\chi_{[0,\tau]}(s) \chi_{[0,t]}(s)dW(s)=\int^{t}_{0}f(s)\chi_{[0,\tau] \cap [0,t]}(s)dW(s)= \int^{\tau \wedge t}_{0}f(s)\chi_{[0,\tau]}(s)dW(s)$